# Overloaded signature supposedly incompatible with supertype, despite not strengthening preconditions

Tags: python, overloading, mypy, python-typing, liskov-substitution-principle

Imagine being given the following base class that you have no control over:

```py
from typing import Optional

class A:
    def foo(self, x: Optional[bool] = None) -> None:
        pass
```

Now you want to write a subclass that merely distinguishes two different call signatures using [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) without actually constraining the parameter types:

```py
# ... import A
from typing import Literal, Optional, overload


class B(A):
    @overload
    def foo(self, x: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def foo(self, x: Optional[Literal[False]] = None) -> None: ...

    def foo(self, x: Optional[bool] = None) -> None:
        pass
```

I would say the two overloaded `B.foo` signatures combined fully cover the possible calls of `A.foo`. I see no violation of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) here since the parameter types  of `B.foo` have not been narrowed.

Yet `mypy` complains about this:

```
error: Signature of "foo" incompatible with supertype "A"  [override]
note:      Superclass:
note:          def foo(self, x: Optional[bool] = ...) -> None
note:      Subclass:
note:          @overload
note:          def foo(self, x: Literal[True]) -> None
note:          @overload
note:          def foo(self, x: Optional[Literal[False]] = ...) -> None
```

Is there something I am missing here or have I stumbled onto a limitation/bug of or `mypy`?

I found this issue [#14725](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14725), which appears to address the same problem, but since nobody reacted yet, I am not sure this is actually a bug. If more people here agree that it is, I can of course simply `# type: ignore[override]` it for now and keep an eye on that issue, but maybe there is a good reason this is forbidden that I just don't understand.

A few other issues I found that seem vaguely related is this one: [#14002](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14002), [#3750](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3750)

---

Tested on Python `3.9`-`3.11` with `mypy==1.1.1`.

For what it's worth, the PyCharm type checker also complains about this, but interestingly it only highlights the *first* overload signature (the one with `Literal[True]`) saying that it does not match that of the supertype.

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something, but your class `B`does not accept an `Optional[Literal[True]]`. So from a static analysis point you are restricting the interface.

Comment: @Wombatz I don't think so. The first acceptable call signature allows `True` as the argument and nothing else. The second acceptable call signature allows `False` or `None` as the argument. Together that means `B.foo` accepts a union of these three. And that is exactly what `Optional[bool]` is. (Taking into account that all else is equal, i.e. no other arguments or different return types.) Aside from that, even if you replace `Literal[True]` with `Optional[Literal[True]]`, the error remains the same.

Comment: Wait, it's the same thing as exhaustive enum overloads: `bool` vs `Literal[True, False]`. Whenever you have `x: bool`, you can't call `B().foo(x)` without narrowing in if-else branches, because `mypy` doesn't union overloads, comparing them one-by-one instead. If none of the overloads fully matches, incompatible call is marked. So it's really not LSP-compliant for `mypy`, because `A().foo(x)` was allowed a is not with `B`.